# AWS Sagemaker: What data format to pass to Estimator?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm following Sagemaker's `k_nearest_neighbors_covtype` example and had some questions about the way they pass their training data to the model.

For those who have not seen it, they load data from the internet, run some preprocessing, then save it to an S3 bucket in some sort of binary format (protobuf/recordIO). Their code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import boto3
import os
import sagemaker
import io
import sagemaker.amazon.common as smac

# preprocess
raw_data_file = os.path.join(data_dir, "raw", "covtype.data.gz")
raw = np.loadtxt(raw_data_file, delimiter=',')

# split into train/test with a 90/10 split
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.shuffle(raw)
train_size = int(0.9 * raw.shape[0])
train_features = raw[:train_size, :-1]
train_labels = raw[:train_size, -1]
test_features = raw[train_size:, :-1]
test_labels = raw[train_size:, -1]

# write to buffer
buf = io.BytesIO()
smac.write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(buf, train_features, train_labels)
buf.seek(0)

# upload to s3
bucket = sagemaker.Session().default_bucket()
prefix = 'knn-blog-2018-04-17'
key = 'recordio-pb-data'

boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(os.path.join(prefix, 'train', key)).upload_fileobj(buf)
s3_train_data = 's3://{}/{}/train/{}'.format(bucket, prefix, key)
print('uploaded training data location: {}'.format(s3_train_data))
```

Later, when calling `model.fit()`, they pass the S3 bucket path as the training dataset.

I'm having trouble understanding how the data needs to be structured from this example and I am also wondering if there is a simpler way to load data directly from a pandas dataframe.

**My Question:**

Let's say after preprocessing I have a pandas dataframe in the following format (~10k records):

```
type         brown   green   red     yellow
NAME                                       
awfulbrown     0.00   33.33   33.33   33.33
candyapple     0.00    0.00  100.00    0.00
grannysmith    2.96   95.19    0.00    0.72
```

I want to pass this to nearest neighbors and have it map/cluster based on `type` (color) weights, with each point labeled by `NAME`. For example, point `candyapple` will be located at 100 on the `red` axis, 0.00 on the `green` and `yellow`. The intention then to pass a new set of color coordinates (eg. `red: 90.09, yellow: 0.33, green: 9.58` would return `candyapple`) and return the single nearest neighbor to that point (the closest approximation of those values we have stored in our records).

1. **What further preprocessing do I need to perform on this dataframe before passing it to Sagemaker's KNN model?**
2. **What is the simplest way to pass the dataframe? Is there a way to pass it directly to the model?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a dataframe directly to the built-in KNN algo. It supports two input training formats: CSV, or RecordIO protobuf: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/kNN-in-formats.html.

The latter is more efficient, so it's the one we recommend.

In your case, you would simply need to convert your dataframe to a numpy array with to_numpy(), and then you can reuse the code in the notebook.

```python
import pandas as pd
index = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': b}, index=index)
n = df.to_numpy()
print(n)
type(n)
```

The notebook you're using is actually showing how to use KNN for classification. This clustering example may be easier to understand: https://data.solita.fi/machine-learning-building-blocks-in-aws-sagemaker/

Comment: Thanks Julien - I was able to get it working. I have another related question if you have time: I noticed when adding labels that the model does not want me to pass my `NAME` col from the df above - it wants numerical labels. I was hoping to use the model to return the names of nearest neighbors, eg. pass in a set of color weights and return the name(s) of nearest points from the training data. Is this a misunderstanding/misuse of Amazon's KNN?

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Quoting from the doc: "For classification problems, the algorithm queries the k points that are closest to the sample point and returns the most frequently used label of their class as the predicted label. For regression problems, the algorithm queries the k closest points to the sample point and returns the average of their feature values as the predicted value". Thus, you can't get individual data point names. You can get the 'k' distances in verbose mode (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/kNN-inference-formats.html).